# Render partial view from Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, .net-8.0

I'm currently new using Razor Pages, the thing is that I'm trying to load a Partial View from a Main View but I'm really strugling because the lack of documentation that I'm founding.

My application is a ASP.NET Core Razor Pages with .NET 8.0

This is how my main view looks:

```
@page "/"
@using Project.Pages
@model PageModel

@section Scripts
{

}

<div class="titulo">
    <div id="iconoPagina" class="float-left gm_iconoCentralita3cx mr-3" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div class="float-left">
        <h1 id="titulo" class="cabecera_Negro"></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="caja col-12 mt-3 py-4">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                @foreach (var value in Model.People)
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @Html.ActionLink(@value.name, "LoadData", "People", new { id1 = value.id1, id2 = value.id2}, new { @class = "sbmt" })
                    </li>
                }
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="partialView">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
using Project.Models.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class PeopleController: Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult LoadData(int id1, int id2)
        {
            PersonalViewModel model = APICall.GetData<PersonalViewModel >(id1, id2, "APIRestEndPoint");

            return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
        }
    }
}
```

The APICall.GetData is just a function that I create that call my APIRest to obtain the data, everything works fine here.

I found that in my Program.cs I need to create a MappControllerRoute in order to my Html.ActionLink works, if I remove this code the links will have a href empty:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=People}/{action=LoadData}/{id1}&{id2}");
```

The thing is that everything works fine, but when the partialview is invoked from the controller it gives me an error telling **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** but I dont know because when I check the viewmodel has data.

I would like to know why the routes are necessary because everywhere I check only using the Html.ActionLink will call the Controller without any addition

Comment: What's your `_PartialView` ? Could you share it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when the partialview is invoked from the controller it gives me an
> error telling Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Make sure you return the partialview with the correct model.  Below I test it with Users model:

```
 public class Users
  {
      public int Id { get; set; } 
      public string Name { get; set; }    
  }
```

LoadData:

```
public IActionResult LoadData(int id1, int id2)
    {
         //PersonalViewModel model = APICall.GetData<PersonalViewModel>(id1, id2, "APIRestEndPoint");
         var model = new Users() { Name="aa",Id=1};
         return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
     }
```

_PartialView:

```
@model PartialRazor.Models.Users

@Model.Name

@Model.Id
```

result:

[image]

> I would like to know why the routes are necessary

The ASP.NET Core MVC template generates conventional routing code , maybe you use Html.ActionLink in it before. The Razor template  doesn't have the route for mvc, so you need to add.

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
...
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You can have a look at [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-up-conventional-route) to know more.

Comment: I still facing the problem, I upload a example project in which I recreate my problem. Could you check it out and let me know where am I wrong?

https://github.com/J003-3/RazorPageIssue/tree/main/WebApplication2

Comment: Hi @J003_  , thanks for your response , I test your code, and find you use a razor page as  the partial view, you can remove  `@page` this line from your _DatosPersonales.cshtml. Besides, you can use right click Shared, then   Add->Add New Scaffollded Item->Razor View->Select `Create as a partial view` to create a partial view.

Comment: "A partial view is a Razor markup file (.cshtml) without a @page directive that renders HTML output within another markup file's rendered output. " you can have a look at [Partial views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to know more.

Comment: Yes!! That was my problem, I remove the @page in my partialview and everything works fine. Thank so much!!